# Angular2 - Why does initializing my array cause problems with my data structure?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a component that is subscribed to some data used to populate a table. This table uses `*ngFor` to loop over the array of data and output it to the page, typical stuff.

When I define my array like so `importResults: ImportResults[];`, my data appears to get stored as intended and I am left with an array of objects.

```
ngOnInit() {
    // Subscribe to our subject that lets us know about the added employees
    this._massEmpService.importedData.subscribe(obj => {
        if (obj) {
            obj.checked = false;
            this.importResults = obj;
        }
    });
}
```

[image]

With this setup, I can use `*ngFor` without issues by simply doing:

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let i of importResults" >
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox"
                    id="checkbox_{{ i.QID }}"
                    [checked]="i.checked"
                    (click)="toggleSelectedEmployee(i)"
                    [(ngModel)]="i.checked" />
        </td>
        ...
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

However... when I initialize my array like so `importResults: ImportResults[] = [];` it alters my data structure.

This leaves me with an array of arrays of objects?

[image]

This causes me to have to do some weird nested looping on my table which doesn't seem right.

```
<tbody *ngFor="let res of importResults">
    <tr *ngFor="let i of res" >
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox"
                    id="checkbox_{{ i.QID }}"
                    [checked]="i.checked"
                    (click)="toggleSelectedEmployee(i)"
                    [(ngModel)]="i.checked" />
        </td>
        ...
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Is this expected behavior to need to nest stuff like this? The first way works fine for how I would expect to be able to loop but because its not initialized, I can't push new data to it which is why I had to go with the expected way of defining it `Array[] = [];`

**Am I doing something wrong here?**

Comment: Without digging deep into it, these sort of JS questions always mean, "somehow I messed up the scope". Are you certain that, every iteration, you are actually creating/returning a new array, or do you continuously modify the old one? And/or, remember, even if the array is new, the references to the objects they hold may not be. So if you act on a "new" array with references to the "old" objects, same effect...you mess with the old(s) array. These days, as a general programming guideline, I would tend to say, "copy everything...figure out optimization later."

Comment: @TimConsolazio - The only thing that I change between to two ways I am doing this is `importResults: ImportResults[]` changes to `importResults: ImportResults[] = [];` and `this.importResults = obj` changes to `this.importResults.push(obj);`.
When doing so, it stores my data in the second array which causes me to have to do the nested loop.

Comment: Somehow that sound wonky. But I'm tired and want to play guitar. I bookmarked this and will address in the morning unless you get an answer.

Comment: @SBB you just explained your own bug: using `push` is wrong. Use `=` instead. Using `push` results in a nested array.

Comment: @SBB, from the code and comments, it looks like `obj` is an array, so when you are initializing `importResults: ImportResults[] = [];` and doing `this.importResults.push(obj);`, you are pushing the array `obj` inside an empty `array` of `[]`. That's why it gets messed up. Instead if you do `this.importResults = obj`, you won't have the problem. The other way would be to take each object from `obj` and `push` them in `importResults` instead of pushing the whole `obj` array.

Comment: I think I got this to work by using `this.importResults.push(...obj);` instead. This allowed me to still push the data as well as remove the nested loop and the data structure remained as expected.

Comment: @SBB but why would you do that instead of assigning the value? Initializing with an empty array is a good thing to do but why should that imply any change to the code in the subscribe callback?

Comment: @AluanHaddad This is like a shopping cart essentially, items get pushed into the array/cart. The user can check boxes on these items that are in the cart and if I overwrite it each time by assigning instead of pushing, it will lose the state of their checked data as it will be replaced entirely.

Comment: @AluanHaddad - I am subscribed to a `BehaviorSubject` if that makes any more sense.. Maybe I am going about this all wrong which is why I ended up here but I am happy to listen to your feedback if you are telling me that I am doing this the wrong way :)

Comment: It sounds like you're overthinking it a little bit but it's hard to say. Initializing with an empty makes sense but only if you do it in the constructor or using inline property initialization. Setting it to an empty array in the `onInit` method doesn't seem useful. Since a behavior subject has initial value you could use that to propagate the initial empty array.

Comment: @AluanHaddad - I am just as confused as you are :)
User picks item, clicks button. This item  has `.next` called on it and sent through the behavior subject which this current component is subscribed to. Data is then rendered to the page via `ngFor` and each item in the cart has a checkbox. I can check all three items in the cart. Now, if I add another item and click the button, this process repeats. By using `importResults = obj` I am replacing the whole shopping cart array so now all those checked boxes are lost. If i `push` it, the items already in the cart remain untouched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first instance, you declare the variable, but don't initialize it, then when you subscribe to the data service you assign the resulting array of objects to the variable:

```
 this.importResults = obj;
```

In your second case, you declare the variable and initialize it as an empty array:

```
importResults: ImportResults[] = [];
```

Then when you get your data back from the service you're doing this:

```
this.importResults.push(obj);.
```

This is taking the returned array of objects from the data service and pushing it into the array you've already created, so that's why it ends up being nested. In the first, you're making your variable equal to the array of objects you're getting back, and in the second you're pushing the array of objects into the existing array.

If you used the same assignment in the second case:

```
 this.importResults = obj;
```

You wouldn't have this problem, whether you initialized the variable to an empty array when you declared it or not.

If what you're trying to do is fetch one or more objects from a service and add them to an existing array, which may already have one or more objects inside, then you want to return the objects via subscribe, and iterate over them, pushing each object in that returned array one at a time into the existing array.

Comment: Thanks - this suggestion was made by others as well but I have convinced myself that I would be better off using `.push(...obj)` instead. However, others said that may be incorrect. While its working for me, I fear now that I have done something wrong elsewhere if this approach was incorrect. Since I want to be able to push new data into this array when I get it and not overwrite it, is `pushing` more appropriate than setting it?

Comment: In the case of a shopping cart, you would start by initializing your cart as an empty array (empty cart), then you would push new items into that cart array one at a time when users click 'add' on items. If you saved that entire cart to a database, and then restored it for them when they came back later, you would fetch the entire cart, which would be an array of objects, and you would assign that fetched array of objects to the cart variable, effectively overwriting whatever was there (probably empty) with their restored cart, and then push additional items as they continued shopping.